# dotenv configure on Loopback 4

Tags: dotenv, loopback4

How to configure `.env` file on `loopback 4` with `dotenv` or other packages to access globally from `process.env.VAR`?

I tried following on `application.ts` but it gives `undefined`.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
...

export class MyApp extends .... {
    constructor (...);
    ....

    dotenv.config();

    ....
}
```

I placed `.env` in `root` as well as `/src` but no success.

Comment: hey dude, I put my dotenv configuration in `index.js` (next to the `package.json`) and it worked !!!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the code like this.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const env_var = process.env.VAR;

export class MyApp extends .... {
    constructor (...);
    ....

    use **env_var**

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the env on the top of class and use it using `process`.

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
...

export class MyApp extends .... {
    constructor (...);
    ....

     process.env.MY_ENV_VAR;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install dotenv in your project:

> npm install dotenv --save

2. Create your *.env* file in *your_project/.env*
3. In the file *your_project/src/application.ts*, add this as the first line:

> require('dotenv').config();

4. Done

I have found it better to put this line *your_project/src/application.ts* instead of somewhere else, as other commands will also get the config, example:

> npm run migrate

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this for a loopback application in particular is via the command line (npm scripts). This is an example for `npm start`:

```
...
"start": "node -r dotenv/config -r your-other-scripts",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install dotenv in your Project
   using following cmd:

> npm install dotenv --save

2. Create .env file in your src folder

> projectname/src/.env

3. Import dotenv file in sequence.ts file.
   ex: ( projectname/src/application.ts )

**In Comman Js**,

> require('dotenv').config();

**In ES6**,

> import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
>
> dotenv.config();

I found that if you use .env file for datasource configuration then you have to import in sequence.ts because when we bulid or project and start application in lb4, 1st file to call is sequence.ts to make connection with datasource, model and repository and then call application.ts